# Codeigniter The requested URL was not found on this server

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am learning Codeigniter and I can't solve the problem I am having.

- When the user access `localhost/reservation/`, the system will display the `login.php` and
- When the user click the login button, the system should redirect the user to another view which the system will display `book.php`.

A good explanation is very appreciated.

**View**

```
<form class="" method="POST"> 
   <div>
       <button class="btn btn-primary" name="login">Login  </button>
   </div>
</form>
```

As you can see, I don't include username and password input fields to shorten the codes.

**Controller**

```
class Reservation extends CI_Controller {
public function _construct()
{
    parent::__construct(;
    $this->load->helper("url");
}

public function index()
{
    if(...some condition...){
        redirect('book');
    }
    $this->load->view('login');
}

public function book(){
    $this->load->view('book');
}
}
```

I shorten the code, removed unnecessary ones(in my opinion) to make it shorter and direct to the point.

**Routes**

```
$route['book'] = 'reservation/book';
$route['default_controller'] = 'reservation';
$route['404_override'] = '';
$route['translate_uri_dashes'] = FALSE;
```

**.htaccess**

```
<IfModule authz_core_module>
    Require all denied
</IfModule>
<IfModule !authz_core_module>
    Deny from all
</IfModule>
```

Comment: have you set .htaccess

Comment: `...some condition...` should be `!is_null($this->input->post('login'))`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, i updated the question to add the .htaccess

Comment: @BinarWeb, i know that. the problem is when `redirecting occurs`.

Comment: put your .htaccess outside the application folder means within your directory folder

Comment: @pradeep, I followed what you said and now, the problem is `Access forbidden.` `You don't have permission to access the requested directory.`

Comment: have you set your base_url in config.php?

Comment: @pradeep, yes as `' '`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Your `.htaccess` should be like this (removing index page):

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

put `.htaccess` file to your app folder outside application folder

and set your `config.php` like this :

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/app_folder/';
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

Now access

```
http://localhost/app_folder/
```

will show you your login page

Comment: add .htaccess , set your base url and access the url , surely you will get what you want

Comment: Nice explanation. Thank you. The `move .htaccess to app root folder` is the main solution and also the codes inside of `.htaccess.

Comment: my pleasure, happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Create a .htaccess file in your `Codeigniter` project directory `myproject/.htaccess`
and add the following code to the .htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```